# Print a binary tree by layer

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

As we know, we can print one binary tree either by level or by [vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521098/print-a-tree-vertically)

I want to print one binary tree by layer. let me explain it through one example.

```
                 1            
            /         \
          2              3       
       /      \       /     \
      4        5      6         7    
    /   \    /   \   /   \    /    \
   8    9  15    12 14   13  10     11
```

For one binary tree above, I want to the output like

```
1st layer: 8 4 2 1 3 7 11
2nd layer: 9 5 6 10 
3rd layer: 15 13
4th layer: 12 14
```

Is my question reasonable? if so, how to do that?

Edit 1:

Explain `layer`

[image]

The circle marked green is the first layer,

The circle marked blue is the second layer,

The circle marked red is the third layer.

Comment: You need to define exactly what you mean by "layer".

Comment: Sorry, I donot know how to express my thought beyond `layer`, because I am not native speaker. I just use one example to explain my quesiton.

Comment: English isn't very helpful. How about a mathematical description? How are we to know exactly what nodes go into each layer?

Comment: Currently I have a way to remove it layer by layer, in the way you want, but i wont be able to distinguish which are the boundary at each layer

Comment: Why 13 and 10 belong to the same layer?

Comment: Is the order of layer output important? I agree with @Kata, not only does it seem to beak the pattern for 13 and 10 to be on the same layer, they're also the only two out of order (not numerically, but positionally)

Comment: its a valid btree, I think he just wants to traverse it ignoring the values

Comment: @Khalos, the order of layer is not important.

Answer (score 1):

### Some clarifications

- I will use C# in my answer. It is easy to translate `C#` to `C++`
- I will have **0-based** arrays, layers and rows as it is common for `C` language
- However, I will **add 1 to them at output** in order to get the desirable output
- I suggest that you store your binary tree in a linear array of size `2n - 1` where `n` is a number of rows. Values where `-1` are non-existent nodes:

  ```
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11 ]
  ```

### Algorithmical solution

Let's draw a proper (in terms of layers, not design) picture of layers:

http://ideone.com/fL4XCx

**If we replace values with layers, it will become:**

```
1
1 1
1 2 2 1
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**We notice that:**

1. Every row of length `n` represents `n \ 2` layers.
2. The first and the last node in a row is always belongs to layer 1.
3. The second one and the `n - 1` is always belongs to layer 2 and so on.
4. Simply said, layers ID are being increased by one from 1 to `n \ 2`, and decreased back to 1.

That's exactly how we will solve this problem: we will traverse through the binary tree level by level and count layer for every node according to these rules.

### Solution code

Actually, the values contained in a tree don't affect the solution. It is only required at output.

Let's declare some variables:

Our array:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11 };
```

`Dictionary<int, int>` (`map<int,int>` in C++).
Key-value pair means that node of index `Key` belongs to layer `Value`:

```
Dictionary<int, int> layers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Some variables:

```
int n = arr.Length,              // Length of array (for convenience)
        nodesInRow = 1,          // How many nodes in current row
        currentNodeInRow = -1,   // Position of node in current row
        rowCenter,               // Center of array (for convenience)
        currentNodeLayer = 0,    // Layer of current node
        maxLayer = -1;           // Maximum layer (we should know how many to output)
```

And the main loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (currentNodeInRow == nodesInRow - 1) // if we are at the end of row
        {
            nodesInRow *= 2; // the count of nodes in binary tree doubles with every row
            currentNodeInRow = 0; // reset to the beginning 
        } else currentNodeInRow++; // go to the following node

        if (i == 0) {
            // 0-th node is a special case as it is the only row with odd count of nodes
            layers.Add(0, 0); 
            continue;
        }

        rowCenter = nodesInRow / 2 - 1; // row center

        if (currentNodeInRow <= rowCenter) // calculate layer according to rules above
            currentNodeLayer = currentNodeInRow;
        else
            currentNodeLayer = nodesInRow - currentNodeInRow - 1;

        if (currentNodeLayer > maxLayer) maxLayer = currentNodeLayer;
        layers.Add(i, currentNodeLayer); 

        // Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", i, currentNodeLayer);
    }
```

Now, we have the following dictionary:

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 1} ...}
```

We can easily output it this because we know the count of layers in our tree:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxLayer; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Layer {0}:", i + 1); // Here we add 1 for 1-based output
    foreach (var x in layers.Where((p) => p.Value == i)) // sorry for being too C#
        if (arr[x.Key] != -1) Console.Write("{0} ", arr[x.Key]); 
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Notice that we didn't work with array of values before output because layers are not affected by the contents of array.

As result, we get the following output:

```
Layer 1: 1 2 3 4 7 8 11 
Layer 2: 5 6 9 10 
Layer 3: 13 
Layer 4: 12 14
```

Here is the [IDEOne Working Demo](http://ideone.com/fL4XCx).

In case you store your binary tree not in plain array but in an array with pointers to ancestors - you can execute BFS to get values in that order and inject it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

i havnt checked, but seems right to me,

the layer number is equal to minimal count between left and right on the branch.

if your tree node is R,R,L,R,R,L.
THEN R-cnt is 4, and L-cnt is 2
therefore its layer 2...

cheers

Comment: @Mox Well, i checked again... 15 is o.k.,  2xL & 2xR => layer 2nd (3rd if you count from 1)

Answer (score 0):

To the answer of @Tomer W I would add two things:

1. Use pre-order traversal (so leftmost is first).
2. Put all your nodes (or some reference to it) + layer in a vector and use stable_sort (on layer) to preserve traversal order among nodes of equal layer

Comment: my answer is completely wrong... was looking right  but it is not !

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be clear and simple now.

First, please re-index the nodes in a standard order:

```
            1            
        /         \
      2              3       
   /      \       /     \
  4        5      6         7    
 /  \    /   \   /   \    /   \
8    9  10   11 12   13  14    15
```

Consider a row, for example:

```
4, 5, 6, 7
```

The first node is a power of 2 number, this number is also the length of the row.

Consider the first half `4, 5` from left to right, we have:

- 4 belongs to layer 1
- 5 belongs to layer 2

Consider the 2nd half `6, 7` from right to left, we have:

- 7 belongs to layer 1
- 6 belongs to layer 2

Thus, in this row, the layer index of a node can be calculated base on the distance from the node to the first and last node.

Here is the code:

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}

int getLayerIndex(int nodeIndex) {
    int firstNode = nodeIndex;
    while ( ! isPowerOfTwo(firstNode) ) {
        --firstNode;
    }
    // Now firstNode is power of 2
    // firstNode is also the length of current row
    int lastNode = firstNode + firstNode - 1;
    return min( nodeIndex - firstNode + 1, lastNode - nodeIndex + 1 );
}
```